# Env variable in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize a basic nodejs app.
My dockerfile is the follow

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

After i build the image I'm trying to running it with

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 imagename -e connectionString=myConnString
```

But I received always the same error

```
[eval]:1
connectionString=myConnString

ReferenceError: myConnString is not defined
```

How can I solve?

Comment: The `-e connectionString=myConnString` should be passed in the `docker run` i.e. `docker run -p 3000:3000 -e connectionString=myConnString imagename` - anything passed after the `image:tag` is passed as `[COMMAND] [ARG...]` to the `ENTRYPOINT` (if any) ref. the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

Comment: great it seems this was my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `docker run` [syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`, anything passed after the `IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST]` is passed as `[COMMAND] [ARG...]`.

The environment variable setting should be passed in the `run [OPTIONS]` i.e.: `docker run -p 3000:3000 -e connectionString=myConnString imagename`

Answer (score 1):

Your docker run command should be:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -e connectionString=myConnString imagename
```

`-e` option should be before `imagename`.

Give it a try.